# Making a variable in Void a global one

Tags: objective-c, function, sms, void

I have a void function which when a button is pressed gets a variable named number. However I have another function where I want to use that variable in.

Here is the code so you can see what I mean.

```
-(void)pictureListMainTableCell:(PictureListMainTableCell *)cell wantsToCallNumber:(NSString *)number
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer =
        [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *message = (@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
        [messageComposer setBody:message];
        messageComposer.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:number  , nil];
        messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;



        [self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"Texting telephone number [%@]", messageComposer);



    }






}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

    switch (result) {
        case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
            break;
        case MessageComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Failed");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (MessageComposeResultSent) {
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", number];
        NSLog(@"calling telephone number [%@]", number);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

So what I want is to be able to use the variable that is named number in the second void. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to automatically call somebody/something as soon as the message being composed gets sent.

Easiest way to do this is to declare an instance variable or property.  For example:

```
@property (strong) NSString * telephoneNumber;
```

Then you can set it in the first function via:

```
self.telephoneNumber = number;
```

And call it from the second function via:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@", self.telephoneNumber];
```

b.t.w., you might find it useful if you name your variables and parameters a bit better.  A NSString object named "number" might confuse you (or somebody else looking at your code later on) into thinking that they're looking at a NSNumber object.